# Chrome developer tools (elements tab) are crawling after including foundation_and_overrides.css in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, google-chrome-devtools

The DevTools used to work just fine with the foundation stylesheet and js, so it has to be something I did that messed things up.

By crawling I mean:

- couple of seconds till any action (js) is triggered.
- couple of seconds traversing with inspect element.

I know it's the foundation_and_overrides.css because removing it makes the DevTools work properly.

If I close the DevTools the app works perfectly - no slow downs on any thing (with the foundation framework)

Comment: I've experienced exactly the same problem with the Sass version of Foundation 5 (stylesheets only).  Fine without, crawling with.

Comment: @richsilv, so you work now with  foundation_and_overrides.css instead of  foundation_and_overrides.scss and it fixed the issue?